# Rectifiable currents

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I found so many definitions of a rectifiable current, which is obviously a current which arises from rectifiable sets, but i really can't get the geometrical meaning of it. I saw some examples of rectifiable currents with a non rectifiable boundary, and the problem was in the fact that the boundary had infinit length. I can't see the link between infinit length and unrectifiability( if such a word exists). Please help me understand;

Comment: You are not really asking a research question, but for help in understanding a known concept.  For that reason, it's not really appropriate for MO.  If you want a good reference that gives lots of examples to build intuitive understanding, try Frank Morgan's book, "Geometric Measure Theory: A Beginner's Guide".  I think that there's not much point in trying to reproduce a section of Morgan's book here.

Answer (score 0):

A rectifiable curve (in the sense of, for example, baby Rudin, p. 136) in Euclidean space or a metric space more generally, is precisely a continuous curve with finite length.